# validates_uniqueness_of when updating car.number

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-3.1

When updating car info, the validation process fails because I have validates_uniqueness_of :number

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
validates :number,numericality: true, length: {is: 7 }
validates :number, :name, presence:true
validates_uniqueness_of :number, :message => "מספר רכב זה קיים במערבת"
belongs_to :owner
has_many :visits
end
```

I need validation to pass, if the original value was not changed, validation on_create would not help since I still need validation when updating.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work for you :

```
validates :number, :uniqueness => {:scope => :number}, :message => "מספר רכב זה קיים במערבת"
```

**OR**

```
validates_uniqueness_of :number, :message => "מספר רכב זה קיים במערבת", :scope => :number
```

Comment: 1. I don't have a column car_id, 2. replaced it with :id, still can update car number to an existing one.

Comment: then maybe `:scope => :number` will help but i am not sure